# Automatic provisioning of Open stack VM for Docker containers

Tags: docker, openstack, mesos, mesosphere

Is there a way to automate the provisioning of open stack VM for Docker Containers? For example I have 3 mesos slaves running on 3 open stack vms and now there are no more VM's left. My next docker containers is waiting to be run and I want open stack to know that my docker container needs a VM and it should automatically instantiate a VM. How to go about it? What open source technologies are available to make this work?

Comment: Can it be done using marathon and mesos?

Comment: Not yet. Auto-provisioning of OpenStack VMs or (AWS/GCE/DO) cloud resources is currently out-of-band of Mesos/Marathon. You'll have to use some external service, perhaps polling the Marathon/Mesos endpoints to detect when you would need to provision another host, and then use OpenStack's tools to do the provisioning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Adam points out this is out of band of Mesos and would require some coding / scripting on your part.   You could however use the mesos-master REST API to determine capacity of the cluster.  {mesos-master ip}:5050/master/stats.json or {mesos-master ip}:5050/system/stats.json should provide good information

Based on values there, you could automate [OpenStack](https://www.openstack.org/).